# Get data from programmatically added view

Tags: java, android

Could somebody help me?

For example, there is the following layout:

**main.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout_item_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        ... Other views, skipped ...

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_add_alias"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_commit" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I use `button_add_alias` to add views as they needed.

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add_alias))
        .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            int position = 1;
            public void onClick (View v) {
                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alias, null);
                ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_item)).addView(view, position);
                position++;
            }
    });
```

**alias.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_alias"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_alias"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    ... Other views, skipped ...

</LinearLayout>
```

So, what is the best way to get data from programmatically added `editText_alias` views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, iterate through your LinearLayout using `getChildAt()`.
Then, retrieve the first child (which in your case will be the `EditText`) from your child view.

```
LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_item);

for (int i = 0; i != parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
   if (parent.getChildAt(i).getId() == R.id.linearLayout_alias) {
       LinearLayout alias = (LinearLayout) parent.getChildAt(i);
       EditText editAlias = (EditText) alias.getChildAt(0);

       // do what you want with the EditText
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do in order to grab the edit text you should be able to call

```
view.findViewById(R.id.editText_alias)
```